# Binding Key Press Events Using Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, key-bindings

I'm new to Python and am trying a bunch of different projects to learn.  I want to use Turtle to create a game and I found this guy on YouTube who walks through re-creating Space Invaders.

I'm using IDLE and Python 3.  The screen and player are created, but nothing happens when I press a key.  I have looked up this issue and tried a number of things, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The other unusual thing is that each function is run once.  I included a print statement in each function to discover this.  Why is it running each key press event once, but not binding to my actual keyboard?

```
import turtle

#Screen setup
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title("Space Invaders")

#Create player
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.color('blue')
player.shape('triangle')
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(0, -250)
player.setheading(90)

playerspeed = 15

#Move the player left and right
def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x -= playerspeed
    player.setx(x)
    screen.listen()
    print("Move left.") #for debugging

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x += playerspeed
    player.setx(x)
    screen.listen()
    print("Move right.") #for debugging

#Create keyboard binding
screen.onkey(move_left(), 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_right(), 'Right')
screen.listen()

#Play game
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with these two lines of code:

```
screen.onkey(move_left(), 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_right(), 'Right')
```

You don't want to call `move_left()`, you want to pass `move_left` to be called by the event handler when the key is pressed:

```
screen.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
```

By including the parentheses, you pass the return value of `move_left()` which is `None`, effectively disabling the event instead of enabling it!

Here's a rework of your code with the above fix plus another trick: space invader type games are perfect for taking advantage of the rarely used `turtle.settiltangle()` method.  This method allows us to make the turtle appear to point vertically, while actually oriented horizontally.  So we can simply used `forward()` and `backward()` to move it across the screen:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

PLAYER_SPEED = 15

# Move the player left and right
def move_left():
    player.backward(PLAYER_SPEED)

def move_right():
    player.forward(PLAYER_SPEED)

# Screen setup
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title("Space Invaders")

# Create player
player = Turtle('triangle')
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('blue')
player.penup()
player.sety(-250)
player.settiltangle(90)

# Create keyboard binding
screen.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

# Play game
screen.mainloop()
```

Of course, you have to remember when you fire a projectile that your turtle is pointing right and redirect it accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

I think the guy you found on YouTube might have been using python 2.7 rather than python 3 which would change the keypress commands.

Instead of

```
screen.onkey(move_left(), 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_right(), 'Right')
screen.listen()
```

You should use

```
screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(move_right, 'Right')
```